# Configure separated GRUB to run Linux from LVM ddrescued device

Tags: grub2, lvm, grub2-mkconfig

I got new 120GB SSD and I want to restore my Linux Mint from my ddrescued `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root`

I splited SSD to 500MB sdb1 Ext4 and 119GB sdb2 LVM as it was before crash.

Then I created `mint-vg` group and made `root` volume. Restored ddrescued Mint image to `mint--vg-root`.

Then I installed GRUB to mounted `sdb1` with this:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/user/mouted_sdb1 /dev/sdb
```

Now when I boot from SSD I get GRUB black screen
I tried [how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux), but GRUB says, that my lvm partitition has unknown filesystem:

```
grub> ls (hd0,msdos <TAB>

Available partititions are

Partitition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type ext* - Last modified .....

Partitition hd0,msdos2: No known filesystem detected - Partitition start at ....
```

I tried `boot-repair` with GUI. It lists my `mapper/mint--vg-root`, but after repair my mint not in list of systems. Mark `mapper/mint--vg-root` as default requires LiveCD.

Tried to:

```
insmod lvm
```

In grub console without result (still no known):

Tried this:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o grub.cfg
```

It says that `/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root` is found, but in `grub.cfg` is no record about this.

How make GRUB to load my Mint from lvm?

**UPDATE**:

Here some Boot Info Summary from my old system and from new. In new I have no "Extended partitition"

**OLD**:

sdb1:

```
File system:       ext2

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info: 

Operating System:  

Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

sdb2:

```
File system:       Extended Partition

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info:
```

sdb5:

```
File system:       LVM2_member

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info:
```

mint-vg-root:

```
File system:       ext4

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info: 

Mounting failed:   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

mint-vg-swap_1:

```
File system:       swap

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info:
```

**new Boot Info Summary**:

sdb1:

```
File system:       ext4

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info: 

Operating System:  

Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
```

sdb2:

```
File system:       LVM2_member

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info:
```

mint-vg-root:

```
File system:       ext4

Boot sector type:  -

Boot sector info: 

Operating System:  Linux Mint 18.1

Boot files:        /etc/fstab
```

**SOLVED** with [how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux) with some modifications in GRUB console:

```
grub> set root=(lvm/mint--vg-root)
grub> linux (hd0,msdos1)/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root
grub> initrd (hd0,msdos1)/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
grub> boot
```

After boot I ran `boot-repair` and it works now.

Comment: So you took an image of your old drive and copied it to the new one using dd?

Comment: Yes. I took image from /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root from old drive. Then put image to new prepared /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root. All with dd

Comment: Probably I had to copy partitition with grub too. But that SSD is gone

Comment: Yeah, taking a copy of the actual disk partitions would have been the best way to go.

Comment: I added old and new boot info summary. Seems different. New is without Extended partitition containing LVM.

Comment: **SOLVED** with https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux with some modifications in GRUB console:

`grub> set root=(lvm/mint--vg-root)`

`grub> linux (hd0,msdos1)/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root`

`grub> initrd (hd0,msdos1)/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic`

`grub> boot
`

After boot I ran boot-repair and it works now

Comment: If it's solved, write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED** with [how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux) with some modifications in GRUB console:

```
grub> set root=(lvm/mint--vg-root)
grub> linux (hd0,msdos1)/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root
grub> initrd (hd0,msdos1)/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
grub> boot
```

Where `(hd0,msdos1)` is `sdb1`.

After boot I ran boot-repair and it works now

Also I fixed UUIDs in `/etc/fstab`, because my boot `/folder` is mounted from `(hd0,msdos1)` partitition. There are all files like `vmlinuz`... and `initrd.img` to boot properly.

Answer (score 0):

i did the same but totally avoided non lvm pointers:

```
grub> set root=(lvm/mint--vg-root)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root
grub> initrd (hd0,msdos1)/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
grub> boot
```

best regards,
alex

Answer (score 0):

In the event you are using efi and not bios boot mode, the commands are just slightly different.  You may need to look for the efi partition with the kernels in addition to the root lvm partition.  I found the intrd image and vmlinuz in the efi partition (hd0,gpt1) for my system.

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt1) (hd0,gpt2) (hd1) (hd1,gpt1) (lvm/mint_vg_root) (lvm/mint_vg_var)

grub> ls (lvm/mint_vg_root)/boot/
./ ../

grub> ls (hd0,gpt1)/
./ ../ efi/ vmlinuz-5.13.0-7620-generic initrd.img-5.13.0-7620-generic

grub> set root=(lvm/mint_vg_root) 
grub> linuxefi (hd0,gpt1)/vmlinuz-5.13.0-7620-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint_vg_root
grub> initrdefi  (hd0,gpt1)/initrd.img-5.13.0-7620-generic
grub> boot
```