# Creating from scratch a bootable M2 disk with backed up image of lvm partition with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, lvm, grub, boot-loader

I had created an `dd` image of `lvm` volume and I would like to restore it on a new pc. The older one is not available right now.

On my old computer, I had 120Gb ssd with something like this:

```
/dev/sda1 as /boot
/dev/sda2 as lvm partition with /dev/mint-vg/root and /dev/mint-vg/swap logical volumes
```

I had created an image of `/dev/mint-vg/root` to restore it on a new computer.

How I should do it on an M2 disk drive?

Now I have 128Gb M2. I had divided it to be similar to the one on the old system:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 ext4 to be "/boot"
/dev/nvme0n1p2 lvm2 pv to be "/"
```

In /dev/nvme0n1p2 I created **mint-vg** volume group with **root** and **swap** logical volumes

I had restored the old `/dev/mint-vg/root` image to the new `/dev/mint-vg/root`.

What I should do next to get `Linux Mint` working again?
Boot-repair did not help, the simple mode did nothing to me, advanced returns black screen after restart.

**UPDATE and SOLUTION**

Problem was how make new system bootable.
I found old copy of /boot folder, copied it to /dev/nvme0n1p1.

Than installed grub with something like:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/dev/mint-vg/root /dev/nvme0n1
```

That gave me grub console. With grub console and [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420383/configure-separated-grub-to-run-linux-from-lvm-ddrescued-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420383/configure-separated-grub-to-run-linux-from-lvm-ddrescued-device) I started system, than ran boot-repair in advanced mode. After several attempts system became bootable.
Now it works.

Comment: "What I should do next to get Linux Mint working again?" What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: Problem was  how make new system bootable.
Solved with something like
`sudo grub-install --root-directory=/dev/mint-vg/root /dev/nvme0n1`

That gave me grub console.

With grub console and https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux I started system, than ran boot-repair in advanced mode.

Now it works

Comment: Senterbo, welcome to U&L! The right thing to do here is to self-Answer by putting the solution into the Answer box, below. Thank you!